# Import a single column dataset (CSV or TXT or XLXS) to act as a list in SQL WHERE IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset that I receive on a weekly basis, this dataset is a single column of unique identifiers.  Currently this dataset is gathered manually by our support staff.  I am trying to query this dataset (CSV file) in my `WHERE` clause of a SQL Query.

In order to add this dataset to my query I do some data transformation to tweak the formatting, the reformatted data is then pasted directly into the `WHERE IN` part of my query.  Ideally I would have the ability to import this list to the SQL query directly potentially bypassing the manual effort involved in the data formatting and swapping between programs.

I am just wondering if this is possible, have tried my best to scour the internet and have had no luck finding any reference to this functionality.

Comment: you might need schedule a weekly job through SQL Server agent utilizing SSIS package to load the file for you.

Comment: @LONG while I don't disagree about the SQL Server Agent job, since there is so little ETL and transformations that need to happen I wouldn't recommend SSIS. This can be can be accomplished with using only TSQL which I've provided an answer showing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `where in` makes this more complex than it needs to be. Store the IDs you want to filter on in a table called *MyTableFilters* with a column of the ID values you want to use as filter(s) and `join` from `MyTable` on *ID* to `MyTableFilters` on *ID*. The join will cause MyTable to only return rows if the ID in `MyTable` is also on `MyTableFilters`

`select * from MyTable A join MyTableFilters F on A.ID = F.ID`

Since you don't really need to any transformations or data manipulation of what you want to ETL you could also easily `truncate` and use `bulk insert` to keep `MyFiltersTable` up to date

`truncate table dbo.MyFiltersTable`

```
BULK INSERT dbo.MyFiltersTable
FROM 'X:\MyFilterTableIDSourceFile.csv'
WITH
(
  FIRSTROW = 1,
  DATAFILETYPE='widechar', -- UTF-16
  FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
  ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
  TABLOCK,
  KEEPNULLS -- Treat empty fields as NULLs.
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you currently have something like the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.UniqueID in ('ID12','ID345','ID84')
```

My recommendation would be to create table in which to store the IDs referenced in the `WHERE` clause. So for the above, your table would look like this:

```
UniqueID
========
ID12
ID345
ID84
```

Supposing the table is called `UniqueIDs` the original query then becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.UniqueID in (SELECT u.UniqueID FROM UniqueIDs u)
```

The question you're asking is then how to populate the UniqueIDs table. You need some means to expose that table to your users. There are several ways you could go about that. A lazy but relatively effective solution would be a simple MS Access database with that table as a "linked" table. You may need to be careful about permissions.

Alternatively, assuming your wedded to the CSV, set up an SSIS job which clears down the table and then imports from that CSV into the UniqueIDs table.